# Libvirt-python package install VS Code Win10/11

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip, lib, libvirt

Is there anyone who successfully install libvirt-python package under Win10/11.

```
PS C:\> pip install libvirt-python
Collecting libvirt-python
  Using cached libvirt-python-8.10.0.tar.gz (240 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: libvirt-python
  Building wheel for libvirt-python (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [47 lines of output]
      Package libvirt was not found in the pkg-config search path.
      Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libvirt.pc'
      to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
      No package 'libvirt' found
      Package libvirt was not found in the pkg-config search path.
      Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libvirt.pc'
      to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
      No package 'libvirt' found
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      Package libvirt was not found in the pkg-config search path.
      Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libvirt.pc'
      to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
      No package 'libvirt' found
```

Is there any way to install under MS?

Answer (score 0):

> No package 'libvirt' found

I refer to this [answer](https://github.com/docker-archive/deploykit/issues/713#issuecomment-334508866) in github.

`libvirt` is a library for virtualization. Infrakit depends on that for the `libvirt` plugin which can provision instances through KVM on Linux.

On the Mac, you can install `libvirt` by using command `brew install libvirt`.

Here's another [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45473463/pip-install-libvirt-python-fails-in-virtualenv), you can read it for more information.